# Android TextView is not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have this small piece of code, and I started using relative layouts and the textview is no longer clickable. I am posting the XML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/fav_list_selector"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:padding="5dip">    
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/pinImage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_9_av_make_available_offline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>    
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/favBusItem"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pinImage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/transpoImage"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:clickable = "true"   
    android:textColor="#000000">        
</TextView>    
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/transpoImage"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pinImage"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_9_av_make_available_offline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

I suspect that the textview is not clickable because of the ImageButton.

Comment: Try adding the `android:clickable="true"` to the `TextView` tag

Comment: yeah.. I tried that (it is in the xml too).. does not work. If I change the ImageButton to ImageView it works. I dont get it. (what could ImageButton be doing to mess it up)

Comment: because image button act as button and your text view is withen it's layout, so image button click event will always take the place when you click on the text view. if you don't use image button click event then add the following lines to it's layout
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I do want to use the image button as clickable (otherwise I would have used imageview), I want two imagebuttons and a textview in between them. All three of them as clickable.

Comment: @Moh.Sukhni - I tried your solution (although I want imagebuttons to be clickable), it did not work.

Comment: @Guru, I'm not confident with this line android:layout_height="match_parent" in the text view if you make the height "wrap_content" your code will work. are you trying to have image button to the right and one to the left and the text view in the middle ?

Comment: Try closing the TextView tag like this: <TextView...content.../>. Your tag is not closed how it should be. Also check if its under something that is transparent. It could be catching its clicks.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I needed another attribute
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
this worked for me.
I added this to the relative layout.

Comment: You might want to consider using `drawableLeft` and [`drawableRight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself.. Anyway here is the answer in case anyone else hits the same issue:

add this attribute for your imagebutton

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

also add

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

for your parent layout

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

use `android:clickable="true"`, in this part of your code:

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/transpoImage"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pinImage"
android:src="@drawable/ic_9_av_make_available_offline"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```